# What is the protective layer around microchips made out of?

Tags: manufacturing, packages, integrated-circuit

I am just curious, what is the dark, almost black material that seems like all microchips are made out of? I did some searching on Google to try and find out, but I can only seem to find the material inside the chip, silicon, which I already knew. I am fairly certain the WHOLE chip isn't made out of silicon anyway.

Thanks!

Comment: What is the part number on the chip? The package material is often encoded into the part number.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The black part of a chip is simply a plastic epoxy resin.

[image: Inside an IC]

Comment: I can see it being plastic for a good number of chips. But sometimes it feels more metallic in nature. I say this, because it is cold to the touch, feels colder than room temperature. Maybe this one I am holding is the ceramic type?

Comment: Possibly, but the plastic is fairly thermally conductive, and contains some metal too. Can you post a photo of it?

Comment: Rocketmagnet, it is at home right now, I can when I get off work. I believe it said Agere AC97 on it. It was from an old modem. I had just gotten a hot-air rework station and I was messing around with it, removing random components from old junk hardware. Here is a link [to a picture of the modem](http://www.flickr.com/photos/58101887@N02/7023713487/)

Comment: The picture you used has a 'bug': **100 mils = 2.54 mm**. You can spot that a mile away (=6.336*10^7 mils)

Comment: @m.Alin - Haha. Yes, well spotted. Let me see if I can fix that.

Answer (score 8):

It is a [moulded epoxy resin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_in-line_package#Construction). Interestingly, [nearly all the worlds supply comes from only two plants](http://findarticles.com/p/articles/mi_m0EKF/is_n1971_v39/ai_14145152/).
Specifically, it is [o-cresol-formaldehyde novolac epoxy](http://www.mendeley.com/research/modification-epoxy-resin-siloxane-containing-phenol-aralkyl-epoxy-resin-electronic-encapsulation-application/) (CNE) according to this paper.

Answer (score 6):

It's an epoxy resin. Early chips had ceramic packages, but they were expensive, and soon replaced by epoxy. Ceramic packaging is still used for high-reliability devices.

Answer (score 5):

Plastic/epoxy or ceramic.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_circuit_packaging

http://www.electroiq.com/articles/ap/print/volume-14/issue-8/features/the-back-end-process/materials-and-methods-for-ic-package-assemblies.html

Comment: What's funny is that the Wikipedia page actually shows a picture of a metal can IC, but doesn't mention anywhere that some IC are canned in metal.

Comment: They use ceramic, as well.

Comment: Wikipedia is also wrong calling COB "rare"; it's quite often used for packaging low cost/high volume devices.